# Regex to isolate state name

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have strings that either look something like 'New Mexico Group' or 'Texas/Dallas Group'.

How can I use regex so that I only have 'New Mexico' and 'Texas' left?

I'm currently using '/.*$' to get rid of everything after the '/' character but I'm not sure how to get rid of 'Group' in the same regex statement for state entries that don't have '/'

Comment: What are the rules you are using?  What database?

Answer (score 1):

The exact way to do this depends on the database.  The following uses `regexp_replace()` to replace the entire string with the part before `'/'` or `' Group'`.  It is using MySQL syntax conventions:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_replace(col, '^([^/]*)(/| Group).*$', '$1')
from (select 'New Mexico Group' as col union all select 'Texas/Dallas Group') t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ae4c50f6c9e26e6c08902106ee88dbf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear in my original question but this helped a lot. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
>>> ex='([a-zA-Z ]+)[[/]*[a-zA-Z ]*]* Group'
>>> re.findall(ex,'New Mexico Group')
['New Mexico']
>>> re.findall(ex,'Texas/Dallas Group')
['Texas']
```

You can find more about regex [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp). You can test and try however it suits you.